# Software client deployment via Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, deployment

is it possible in Sharepoint to deploy software via a server to client PCs, something like Secunia CSI, but with Sharepoint?
There's Sharepoint Inventory, could this be used or am I misunderstanding it?

Regards

Comment: Could you please provide a link with more information on "SharePoint Inventory"?

Comment: I guess I called it wrong, should have been "Access App". See https://youtu.be/NrUzwkfPc4M?t=27

Comment: This is an example how to build a Inventory inside AccessApp on SharePoint. It's not much more than an intelligent list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say "this is not possible", even this answer is just 99.9% accurate.

0.1%: You could develop an own solution with external agents to achieve this job. BUT: If this idea would be useful to be implemented on SharePoint, there would be a 3rd party addon for that.

My recommendation: Do not misuse SharePoint to deploy software to clients. Use a tool that was designed to do that job (System Center, Baramundi, Secunia, ...). If you do not want to spend money, you even could make use of GroupPolicies which install software to clients.